# Django website deploy errors: Failed building wheel for Pillow, Reportlab in cPanel

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

My website is working fine on the local server. This error is coming up when I try to install Pillow on the server (Namecheap Shared Hosting). I talked to Live Support, they have enabled the compiler, but still, I am getting these errors. Is there anybody to help me, how can I fix this?

[image: Error Screenshot 1]
[image: Error Screenshot 2]
[image: Error Screenshot 3]

Comment: What version of python? IDK what you're doing, but if it's  ```pip install Pillow```, try ```python -m pip install Pillow```

Comment: Python 3.8
Still not working on cPanel Terminal

Comment: You can install it from source if pip doesn't work, but it says you're on version 9 of pip, whereas version 23 is available. Also, it looks like you don't have the `long_file_path_name/gcc` installed (the file it can't find). That's a c++ compiler. Not sure if you need that. I would first try upgrading pip, if not that install it from source, and if not that install gcc.

Comment: Issue solved. Thank you so much (sin tribu)

Comment: Note for your next question, do not put images of text.  A question must be a self contained work, that remains valid even if the images or links go bad.  You should take the [tour], and read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @ManikMia how did you solve the issue? Can you share the solution please?

Comment: @MuhammadZubair I changed the python version 3.8 to 3.7(Namecheap Shared Hosting). Then I run "pip install pillow==8.0.0" and It's worked. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm answering your question with your solution so that anyone else could also easily see it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@ManikMia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17301973/manik-mia) who was himself able to find the solution. So, here is the solution that he devised, and it worked for me too.

Firstly, change the Python version to `3.7`, and then run `pip install pillow==8.0.0`.
Be careful about the pillow version also.

This is for the Namecheap shared Hosting